# MySQL DATA Truncation Error occuring from Java GUI application but not directly on MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Using a java program, am trying to update 3 colums in a table (the same table) on click of a button but when i try, to run it, it generates an error.
This is the error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'javax.swing.jTextField[,20,34,14x29,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,borde'
```

And heres my code

```
private void SaveBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
         // method for treating patient 

        try{

            String sql = "UPDATE `iClinic`.`Treatment` SET `ProblemDesc` = ?,`Comments` = ?,`RescheduleDate` = ? WHERE `Treatment`.`RegID` ='"+PRegIDTF+"'";

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, descriptionTA.getText());
            pst.setString(2, CommentsTF.getText());
            String value = ScheduleDateDT.getDate().toString();
            pst.setString(3, value);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "saved");
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: And what is `PRegIDTF`?

Comment: its the name of the jTextfield holding the value i want to use

Answer (score 0):

The mistake/ problem was that in the SQL statement, i had only included the name of the jtextfield withoud including the command or method to fetch d result o value in that jtextfield. so the solution/ correction would be as below;

String sql = "UPDATE `iClinic`.`Treatment` SET `ProblemDesc` = ?,`Comments` = ?,`RescheduleDate` = ? WHERE `Treatment`.`RegID` = '"+PRegIDTF.getText()+"'";